# how can i make this stream code as for-loop in java?

Tags: java

guys.
I was doing my project for now, and then making service layers for this codes of reading select query, i have a question now.

i am pretty new web developer, so I am kinda confused of JAVA8 especially about lambda and stream.

```java
//this code is on service layer to read db.
public List<CouponResDto.CouponInfo> getValidCoupon(OrderInDto.Search condition) {
        return toList(repository.findAll(condition.getCondition()))
                .stream()
                .map(this::toCouponInfo)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

//to respond as Dto not entity.
public CouponResDto.CouponInfo toCouponInfo(Coupon coupon) {
        return new CouponResDto.CouponInfo()
                .setName(coupon.getName())
                .setAmount(coupon.getAmount())
                .setDescription(coupon.getDescription());
    }
```

```java
    @Data
    @Accessors(chain = true)
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class CouponInfo {
        Long id;
        String name;
        int amount;
        String description;
    }
```

I wanna know how the "getValidCoupon" works, and make the code using for-loop, not stream.
Can i get this logic?

Comment: That's a simple `for` loops that adds the value returned by `toCouponInfo` passing it each element of `toList(repository.findAll(condition.getCondition()))`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thanks for comment! yes i thought so, but the toList(repository.findAll(condition.getCondition())) isnt same type with List<CouponResDto.CouponInfo> because the toList is from repository. so, how can i match the type? Lets say toList is entity, the other one is Dto...

Comment: The code wouldn't work as-is if `toList` didn't return a `List<Coupon>`, so I think it's a safe bet to assume it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `for` loop the code would look like this:

```java
public List<CouponResDto.CouponInfo> getValidCoupon(OrderInDto.Search condition) {
    List<CouponResDto.CouponInfo> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (var item : toList(repository.findAll(condition.getCondition()))) {
        result.add(toCouponInfo(item));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but im sorry :( im using java8, i dont have var...

Comment: I used `var` because I have no information about the type of entity returned from the repository, so you can easily replace `var` with this type (e.g. `CouponEntity`) of your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than rewriting it as a for-loop, here is an inline description of each step of the Stream implementation.

```
public List<CouponResDto.CouponInfo> getValidCoupon(OrderInDto.Search condition) {
  // Capturing result in local variable to be returned afterward just to make documentation easier to follow
  List<CouponResDto.CouponInfo> result =
        /**
         * execute the findAll query on the repository and pass the results
         * to our toList(..) method to produce a List<Coupon>
         */
        toList(repository.findAll(condition.getCondition())) // <-- List<Coupon>
        /**
         * invoke the List.stream() to stream the contents of that List
         */
        .stream() // <--------------------------------------------- Stream<Coupon>
        /**
         * Invoke the Stream's map(..) method to convert each Coupon to a
         * CouponResDto.CouponInfo using our toCouponInfo(..) method
         */
        .map(this::toCouponInfo) // <------------------------------ Stream<CouponResDto.CouponInfo>
        /**
         * Invoke the Stream's collect(..) the CouponResDto.CouponInfo instances
         * into a new List
         */
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // <------------------------ List<CouponResDto.CouponInfo>
  // Return the List
  return result;
}
```